# Help with java on Fedora

Tags: fedora, java

I have installed java on my fedora, because when I execute `java -version` I get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode).
```

But I am unable to open `.jar` files because I can't find the option to open it with openjdk, and it is not working via the terminal either.

Comment: There's a `-jar` option to the `java` command that you could use to specify that you're giving it a jar file instead. [Relevant Question from ask fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/36107/how-to-launch-jar-file-with-openjdk/). Without seeing the error you're getting it's hard to say for sure what you're actually running into, though.